# Iteratively delete elements from array

Tags: perl

I have an array, `@cuts`, of indices of the elements that I would like to remove from `@Data`. Is this an appropriate way to do so?

```
foreach (@cuts){

    $Data[$_] = "NULL";

}


for my $i (0 .. $#Data){
    if ($Data[$i] eq "NULL"){
        splice(@Data,$i,1);
        } 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use a sentinel value (`"NULL"`).

```
my %cuts = map { $_ => 1 } @cuts;
my @keeps = grep !$cuts{$_}, 0..$#Data;
@Data = @Data[@keeps];
```

This can surely be simplified by merging it with the preceding code.

Comment: I am very confused as to why this works, but this is the best solution. My subroutine was working on a global array (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24812456/subroutine-that-processes-the-array-it-returns), and this was the only one that removed elements not only in the scope of the sub but also in the main scope `my @newData = grep { !/^NULL\z/ } @Data;` removes them in the sub, but then they get replaced by blanks in the main program...

Answer (score 2):

```
my @newData = grep { !/^NULL\z/ } @Data;
```

Answer (score 2):

Combining @toolic and @user2752322:

```
delete @Data[@cuts];
my @newData = grep { defined } @Data;
```

Comment: `undef @Data[@cuts]` or `@Data[@cuts] = ()` would be preferable to `delete`.

Comment: @ikegami The documentation for delete warns that its use on array values is deprecated (although I'm admittedly unaware of the current attitude toward it on p5p--the warning may be outdated, it's been around since at least 5.12). Plus it conveys intent better to `undef` the values you don't want, then grep the remaining `defined` values.

Comment: @Slade, Oops, yeah, was confused because there's no actual harm in using `delete` on array elements. Using `undef` on variables, on the other hand, is usually a bad idea unless you specifically intend to defy the optimization it defies. Doesn't matter for a slice, though. Assigning `undef` (as you unclearly did in your second snippet) is always fine, except it prevents `undef` from naturally existing in `@Data`.