# Subroutine that processes the array it returns?

Tags: perl

I would like to

```
my @Array;

for (my $i=1; $i <= 10000; $i++) {

ProsArray(\@Array);

}


sub ProsArray {

  my @Array = @{$_[0]};
  #do stuff to @Array (e.g., remove or add elements...
  push(@Array,10);
  return(@Array);

}
```

But, the subroutine acts on my `@Array` that was initially declared--not on the `@Array` it returns in the previous iteration.

I would like something like

```
while(...){
@Array = ProsArray(\@Array);
}
```

So it would process the returned array and not the initial.

Comment: And what's wrong with the code you wrote?

Comment: In the subroutine, I am removing some elements of `@Array`. When I print it out after doing so (in the soubroutine), the array is as I want it: with the elements removed. However, when the subroutine tries to process it in the next iteration, those elements are still removed but in their place are `undef` values (when I print the array before calling the subroutine, in other words, it prints out blank lines where the elements that I deleted used to be).

Comment: I think that could be because you are calling it like `ProsArray(\@Array)`. get rid of the reference '\'

Comment: use of the `delete` function is deprecated for arrays...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to operate on your array inplace, you need to work against the reference you pass. Alternately, you need to store the return value.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Printer;

my @array_inplace = (1 .. 5);
my @array_return = (1 .. 5);

for (1 .. 3) {
    ProsArrayInplace(\@array_inplace);
    @array_return = ProsArrayRet(\@array_return); # replace array with retval
}

sub ProsArrayInplace {
  my ($array) = @_;
  #do stuff to @$Array (e.g., remove or add elements...
  push(@$array,10); # modify in place
}

sub ProsArrayRet {
  my @array = @{$_[0]}; #dereference
  #do stuff to @$Array (e.g., remove or add elements...
  push(@array,10); #modify array scoped to sub
  return @array; #return modified array
}

p(@array_inplace);
p(@array_return);
```

Results:

```
[
    [0] 1,
    [1] 2,
    [2] 3,
    [3] 4,
    [4] 5,
    [5] 10,
    [6] 10,
    [7] 10
]
[
    [0] 1,
    [1] 2,
    [2] 3,
    [3] 4,
    [4] 5,
    [5] 10,
    [6] 10,
    [7] 10
]
```

Comment: Alternately, you can operate on the global array in your code by removing the `my @Array = @{$_[0]};` and the `return(@Array);` and just operating on the global `@Array` directly. Keep in mind that global values all over the place tends to lead to issues with unexpected size effects, though, and it's better to keep variable scope as tight as possible. Using the two forms in the answer is generally preferred over the global scoping design.

Answer (score 2):

From the comments:

I believe the problem you are facing is caused by the way you are doing recursion.

In

```
@Array = ProsArray(\@Array);
```

You pass the same reference in to the original @array object every time. Try removing that "\" and rerunning your code.